# OOP design: one object dependent on the existence of ALL its dependencies

Tags: c++, oop

Just a heads up, I have received little formal education on this type of design theory, so bear with me if I'm ignorant of some concepts. All of my reasoning comes from a background in C++. I am working on a component based system for use in a game engine, and this is the structure I have come up with.

- There are components, which are just data.
- There are nodes, which allow access to that data.
- There are systems, which operate on nodes only.
- There are Entities, which contain these nodes, components, systems, and other entities.

Pretty straightforward, but let's just focus on the components and nodes, which I have a pretty strict set of guidelines for.

1. a node can provide access to a collection of components within an entity
2. a node is dependent upon the existence of *all* its underlying components
3. a component can exist independent of any node pointing to it.
4. a system can only have access and act upon nodes

Now any of these nodes and components can be destroyed at any time. I've implemented this for nodes by using a set of intrusive lists to maintain a non-ownership method of iterating across nodes, and then they automatically remove themselves from the list upon their destruction. But now I have a question revolving about the components. On destruction of some component, all nodes must also be destroyed who were dependent upon that component. Normally, the simple fix to an object needing to be destroyed when another is destroyed is ownership, where you simply place the node within the component or dynamically destroy it within that components destructor, but nodes here can reference multiple different components. When an object has multiple owners, normally a ref counting solution like a smart pointer gives ownership to all those objects and is destroyed when all owners are destroyed, but that isn't the case this time. My big question, what do I do in terms of ownership when I have one object that can only exist when *all* its dependencies exist, and upon the destruction of *any* dependency, results in the destruction of that dependent object.

example:

[Red are components needed for the existence of the second node](https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/embeddedchart/4f63-bde4-53020eda-89bd-0eb90a00cee2)

[What it looks like after either component it depends on is destroyed](https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/embeddedchart/4d54-3d44-530f0e8e-bf92-1aa20a005bed)

Obviously, there are multiple unclean solutions with weak pointers, manual deletions, and lots of checks for an objects existence, but like all issues, I'm wondering if this can be safely achieved by design alone. Again, if this is a very simple or well known concept, please just point me in the right direction.

**@Jorgen G Valley** - All of the objects are indeed owned by the entity, in that all objects are destroyed on destruction of the containing entity, but nodes, components, systems, and entities should be able to be added or removed at any time dynamically. Here is an example. Start with the world entity, which contains an entity which is one mesh and two vectors. The two vectors are updated independently, but let's say you want to parent them together, you would simply add a node, specify one vector as the parent, and any number of vectors as children. The addition of the node to the entity places it in a non-owning list, allowing the previously existant "Parent" system to iterate through all "Parent" nodes and perform functionality on each parent node. Unparenting the object involves just deleting the node, but then the vector and mesh should still exist. Let's say you want to destroy just that vector and hold onto the mesh for use in another model, than the destruction of that vector should also destroy the parent node, because it no longer references a valid vector.

Here are some visuals:

here is an example of the case above. [here](https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/embeddedchart/4051-525c-530f7d50-b957-5d210a009107)

now here is an example of removing the parent node. [here](https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/embeddedchart/410b-36d4-530f7f18-b06a-7a150a009433)

notice that the component stays around because it could be used in other nodes, like in this example, where the render node is using it. The destruction of the node closed the gap in the intrusive list used by the parent system, meaning the parent system only manages whatever other entities have parent nodes.

now here is an example of removing the vector component. [here](https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/embeddedchart/40de-8208-530f7f46-aa36-7e650a004e78)

In this case, all nodes dependent upon that vector must be removed as well, including the parent and render node. There destruction closes the gaps in those respective intrusive lists, and the systems continue on there way. Hopefully this helps illustrate the design i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It feels to me as if the design, "component removes itself from node's non-owning list" extends cleanly to, "component destroys the node". Is that the case here?

Comment: I probably shouldn't have mentioned the non-owning list, that is just the way a system accesses nodes without ownership. The problem is definately, component destroys the node, but since a node can reference any number of components. The question changes to, "ANY component which the node depends on destroys the node" which is my confusion. Is there a design that wouldn't involve components holding weak references and manually deleting the object referenced, forcing all the other components who that node depends on to check for the existence of the node? (the nasty solution).

Comment: Can part of destroying the node be, to remove it from its components? One of which is about to die anyway, the rest perhaps not.

Comment: Have you tried programmers.se

Comment: Why do you want to destroy an object that another object depends on? What I see in the diagrams is systems that own Renderers and Parents, which in turn own Vectors and Meshes. As such, Vectors and Meshes should just not be deleted unless all their references are removed, i. e. plain old ref-counting. Why do you want to destroy them directly?

Comment: @SteveJessop - how would the node remove itself from it's components? Maybe like a vector of refs in the component to nodes where when a component is destroyed it finds that nodes ref and deletes the node, and then in the destructor of the node, it iterates over all it's components, and informs them of it's destruction by removing his entry from the vector in the other components? That could work, but I feel it would add unneeded complexity or it may be too difficult to keep those internals outside the hands of the end user. Still, I hadn't thought of it like this, i will give it a try.

Comment: @cmaster - Here's an example of it's use. Let's say the mesh is of a soccer ball. This entity is then two parented soccer balls. Then let's say there is a prism that when encountered, one should vanish, but not the other? I would delete the vector, and then one soccer ball would be left rendering as normal. The parent node should vanish as well as the second soccer ball. Also, the systems own nothing. When destroyed the nodes and components will remain existing, influenced by any other systems that may work on those types of nodes.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: I don't know how, but I figure if a node is dependent on a component then the component must somehow be reachable from the node. Otherwise how can it be dependent if it has no way of knowing whether it exists or not?

Comment: @SteveJessop - The node definitely maintains references to the components, i just hadn't thought of the components containing references to the nodes, since they do not individually own a node, but that idea of having weak references in each component in a set , like a raw pointers, I could have the component delete the dependant nodes, and then have the node tell it's managed components that it's on it's way out the door (to remove the node from the component's list of dependant nodes). It actually makes a lot of sense. Will update with results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating things a bit more than you need. You say that nodes and components can be destroyed at any time. Is this really true?

In your text you describe the entity as the owner since you say it contains the components, nodes and systems.

My approach to this would be that a component would only be destroyed when the entity owning it is destroyed. This means that the node, component and system doesn't need to bother about destruction. It is done by the owning object, the entity.

EDIT: If you have situations where the component, node or system can be destroyed without the overlying entity to be destroyed I am intrigued to hear an example. It's a really interesting problem in itself. :)

Comment: @Jorgen_G_Valley - placed my response in main question for more room.